# SQL query to select rows that based on some value of other rows in the same table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Assume I have the following `activity` table:

```
id     type   value   flag
------|------|-------|------|
1     |A     | 13    | 1    |
2     |B     | 29    |      |
3     |C     | 11    |      |
4     |A     | 78    |      |
5     |X     | 91    |      |
6     |C     | 2     |      |
7     |B     | 14    | 1    |
```

I want to select rows that any row with the same type has the flag `1` or the type is `X`. In this case, I would like to get:

```
id     type   value   flag
------|------|-------|------|
1     |A     | 13    | 1    |
4     |A     | 78    |      |
2     |B     | 29    |      |
7     |B     | 14    | 1    |
5     |X     | 91    |      |
```

I can do an `INNER JOIN` to get the result like:

```sql
SELECT
  "activities".*
FROM "activities"
INNER JOIN activities AS a2
  ON activities.type = a2.type
  AND a2.flag = 1
  OR activities.type = 'X'
  AND activities.id = a2.id
```

However, this is slow when the amount of records becomes large, especially when I need to do a `COUNT(*)` on top of the result. I wonder how I can rewrite the query and make it more performant.

I am using Postgres. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 ways to do it. Choose one which will be work faster on your dataset. To speed up these queries you have to create indexes on `type` and `flag` fields.

```
select a.* from activities a
JOIN (select distinct type FROM activities where type='X' or flag=1) t
ON a.type=t.type;


select a.* from activities a
where type='X'
  or EXISTS(SELECT * FROM activities WHERE type=a.type AND flag=1);


select a.* from activities a
where type='X'
  or type IN (SELECT type FROM activities WHERE flag=1)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c2413/8)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution

```
SELECT id,
       type,
       value,
       flag
FROM (SELECT *,
      SUM(CASE WHEN flag = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY type) AS flag_occurence_for_type
      FROM activities) t
WHERE type = 'X' OR flag_occurence_for_type > 0
```